# Coherent types per generic item in an array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So, my idea is to have an array of generic items like this:

```
interface Item<T extends {} = {}> {
  out: () => T;
  in: (data: T) => void;
};
```

but then, when defining the array, the only thing I can think about is something like:

```
type ItemArray<T extends {} = {}> = Item<T>[];
```

the problem then if I define the array like that, is that every item of the array has the same type, and what I want to do is:

```
interface A { n: number }
interface B { s: string }
const arr = [
  { out: () => { n: 1 }, in: (data: A) => void },
  { out: () => { s: 'txt' }, in: (data: B) => void },
];
```

As you can see, the `out` and `in` members of each item of the array, have *coherent types* but the array itself is kind of generic.

Also, I can't define the array as `ItemArray<A | B>` because then, it complains that A doesn't have all members of B, etc.

Nor I want to do `ItemArray<A & B>` because when accessing each member, there's no help on what kind of parameter it should accept (it gives me the union of all types).

I was looking to do something more like...

```
const arr = [
  item0 as Item<A>, // the hint of "as Item<Type>" shouldn't even
  item1 as Item<B>, // be needed if TS infers it properly
];

// if I do this, TS should know that out0 is type A
const out0 = arr[0].out();
// and if I do this, out1 should be inferred as B
const out1 = arr[1].out();
```

but I haven't found the way yet to make TypeScript proper infer the types per item automatically, based on the return type of the `out` member or the accepted type of the `in` function.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the type of `array[0]` and `array[1]` to be different, then `array` needs to have a tuple type like `[Type0, Type1]` instead of an array type like `(Type0 | Type1)[]`.

Fortunately, it is easy to get Typescript to infer a tuple type from an array literal instead of an array type: just add `as const`. For example:

```js
const array = [1, 'foo'] as const;

let zero: number = array[0];
let one: string = array[1];
```

Comment: The `as const` here is the only way to get the behavior you are looking for. If the array of items can be any length and have any items in the array, there is no way for typescript compiler to infer which type any given element in the array is - in this sitiuation, type is only known at runtime without `as const`. And, if the array is always the same length and order of types, I do not see a reason to use `Array` type in this situation. You would be better off using [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) or just a regular old object.

Comment: The `as const` solution doesn't work because it loses the inferred types of the parameters of the internal functions of each object of the array... and the `tuple` solution is not valid because is **too** simple (I tried to simplify my case enough to formulate a valid question). The actual problem array hasn't a fixed number of elements, and the order of each element is not fixed (so it can be `[A, B, C]`, or `[C, B]`...). I guess it's a complex case, but it feels like it should be possible :P

Comment: Well, if the array could be either `[A, B, C]` or `[C, B]`, how should the compiler infer that `arr[0]` is of type `A` and not `C`?

Comment: I was hoping the compiler was smart enough to infer the types of the elements from their properties (because the array is declared as a constant). As shown in the question, if the first item function accepts a `number`, then the type of the first item is `number`, if the second item accepts `T`, then it's `T`, etc.

Comment: But I can see it's not possible because doing something as `const arr = [1, 'x']` won't infer it as a tuple like `[number, string]`, but it infers it as `(number | string)[]` instead :( -- it's possible if it's declared as `const arr = [1, 'x'] as const`, like you proposed (which I didn't knew and I learned today! ^^) ~~ but still doesn't solves my real case :(

Comment: I see. Well, sorry that I wasn't able to help with your problem, anyway.